# resume music after go another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I was trying to build a music app. music is playing when I stay in my music view controller. I also set music background mode. music is playing in background mode, but when I go to another view controller. music is restarted. what is the problem?

here is what i try

```
  //this is global variable 

    var player : AVPlayer?
    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?

override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
           musicplayer()
           play()
    }



 func musicplayer(){

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                print("AVAudioSession is Active")

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    }
```

This is my player play

```
    func play(){
    let musicUrl = totalAlbumList[myIndex].audiofile
            if let mm = musicUrl {
                var url: URL!
                url = URL(string: mm)
                playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
                player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                player?.volume = 1.0
                player?.rate = 1.0
                player?.play()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place your AVPlayer and all the code related to player in singleton class if you want to play music in all classes.

Background mode will only help when application is in background mode and your UIViewController is running.
Use below class to play music.

```
//
//  MusicPlayer.swift
//  MusicPlayer
//
//  Created by Lakhwinder Singh on 11/09/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 lakh. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class MusicPlayer: NSObject {

    //Constant varialbe of class
    static let player = MusicPlayer()

    //this is global variable
    var player : AVPlayer?
    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?

    func initPlayer(){
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                print("AVAudioSession is Active")

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func playMusic(_ musicUrl: String?) {
        if let mm = musicUrl {
            var url: URL!
            url = URL(string: mm)
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            player?.volume = 1.0
            player?.rate = 1.0
            player?.play()
        }
    }

}
```

Just call below code in your AppDelegate to initialise the player.

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        MusicPlayer.player.initPlayer()
        return true
    }
```

And use this code in your class.

```
MusicPlayer.player.playMusic(totalAlbumList[myIndex].audiofile)
```

Comment: How can i add **addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: timeIntarval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (progressTime)** in in this

Comment: Either, you can add protocol in MusicPlayer Class to get time or you can add variable for completion block to access in main class.

Comment: @SporshiyaIslam, It it helps, then you can vote me up :)

Comment: Why the double `do {...} catch` block around `.setActive(true)`?